# ssh2_scp_send okay for first time but fail the second time

Tags: php, ssh, scp

I am making use of php ssh2_scp_send to transfer files to the remote machine, but it is a bit weird, it works for the first time but fails my second call with the following error

```
//success for file transfer
if (!(ssh2_scp_send($this->conn, $lpath, $rpath, 0777))){
            throw new Exception("File transfer failed!");
        }
        ssh2_exec($this->conn, 'exit'); 

//fail this time
if (!(ssh2_scp_send($this->conn, $lpath, $rpath, 0777))){
            throw new Exception("File transfer failed!");
        }
        ssh2_exec($this->conn, 'exit')
```

"Warning: ssh2_scp_send(): Failed copying file in /var/www/trunk/rsetting/class/ssh.class.php on line 57"

Any help will be appreciated~Thanks

Comment: Because you have closed the connection on the after the first transfer..  `ssh2_exec($this->conn, 'exit');`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have deleted that code but the problem still here :(

Comment: Yes, exactly the same error

Answer (score 0):

update php-ssh2 extension to 0.13 will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but solved it by calling this function:

`ssh2_exec($conn, 'exit');`

at the end of the loop.
I think this command flush the buffer and write correctly the last remote file.